# Adventure mechanic

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-adventure-cards

I've got some questions regarding Adventure mechanic. I understand the basic rules of this mechanic, but I've got a few more detailed questions.

1. If some effects allow you to find a sorcery or instant in your library, hand or graveyard, can you find adventure card?
2. When some effect lets you cast instant or sorcery from your graveyard, can you cast adventure?
3. If after using adventure I play creature from exile, and this creature is returned to my hand, can I use adventure mechanic again?

Comment: Question 2 is a duplicate: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/48801/can-i-cast-adventures-from-my-graveyard

Comment: Question 3 is a duplicate: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/49916/return-a-creature-with-an-adventure-to-hand-can-i-cast-the-instant-sorcery-agai

Comment: The answer to question 1 is at the bottom of this answer: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/50747/7948

Comment: Also for question 1 see https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/49471/do-adventure-cards-count-towards-number-of-instant-and-sorcery-cards-in-your-gr for a related problem that would have a similar conclusion.

Comment: Please check out the suggestions for answers that where listed and if they don't provide answers update the question so only one is being asked and ask additional ones in a new question,

Comment: Please check my edit and verify that I properly understood your question. You may also want to add more information for why some of the linked questions don't answer your question. You'll probably want to update the title as well.

Comment: "But I found information that such effects work in this case and you can use them on Adventure cards." Please share your finding so we have something concrete to discuss.

Comment: This question is like a game of telephone. After two clarification edits, it says things the original question never said. @Hackworth you are asking about a statement that does not come from the original question author, so you are unlikely to get a useful answer. I believe this question has changed too substantially, so I rolled it back to its original content.

Comment: The link to this "found information" is in the first comment below my questions.